# pytest get the file path of current test file

Tags: python, pytest

I can't seem to get the file path of the current file being tested in pytest.

For instance consider something like the following directory structure:

```
devops_scripts
├── devops_utilities
│   ├── backupMonthly.py
│   ├── generateAnsibleINI.py
│   └── tests
│       └── test_backup.txt
├── monitoring
│   ├── analyizeCatalinaLog.py
│   ├── fetchCatalinaLogs.py
│   └── getaccountcredit.py
├── pi_provisioning
│   ├── piImageMake.sh
│   ├── piImageRead.sh
│   └── piImageSquashSd.py
└── script_utilities
    ├── README.md
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── execute.py
    ├── path_handling.py
    ├── sql_handling.py
    └── tests
        ├── sourcedirfortests
        │   ├── file1.txt
        │   └── file2.txt
        ├── test_ansible.txt
        └── test_execute.txt
```

If I run `pytest` from the top level it will descend to testing `test_execute.txt`. When `test_execute.txt` is under testing how do I get the file path to it? (I can get the `rootdir` through `os.path.abspath('.')` but that is not what I need)

(I need to be able to set these paths in order to test some execution things on `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. I also need this to work no matter how deeply nested the various things I am trying to test.) I am not so interested in setting up specific temp testing directories and taking them down, etc. I just need the path of the file which is being tested.

I have tried things like:

```
>>> print os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

But that just yields: `UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION: NameError("name '__file__' is not defined",)`

I am not above even accessing some internal functions / objects in py.test

(I should add that I need this to work in Python 2.7 and Python 3.x)

Comment: `os.path.abspath(__file__)` resolves as expected for me in PY3.6 under pytest.

Comment: `__file__` only works in actual python files, not the interactive shell.

Comment: @StephenRauch I should add that I need this to work in Python2.7 as well.

Comment: @JasonHarris, and you think `__file__` has changed from Py2 to Py3?

Comment: @StephenRauch Well it doesn't work in pytest when I tried it: `================== FAILURES ========== __________ [doctest] test_execute.txt _________ 006 >>> import sys 007 >>> print(os.path.abspath(__file__)) UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION: NameError("name 'file' is not defined") Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/doctest.py", line 1329, in run compileflags, 1), test.globs) File "<doctest test_execute.txt[6]>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name '__file' is not defined `

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pytest sets PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST env var for the current running test. Not only it has current file info, it has info of current collected test id too (like test name, params etc.).

```
import os
def test_current():
    print(os.getenv('PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST'))
```

You must use `-s` flag for pytest run if you want to see the printed text.

From [Reference Doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#pytest-current-test-env):

> During the test session pytest will set PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST to the current test nodeid and the current stage, which can be setup, call and teardown.

Comment: Hallelujah! It works!! Thank you so much! (I removed my old comment about the previous solution not working)

Comment: From the same doc:
"The contents of PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST is meant to be human readable and the actual format can be changed between releases (even bug fixes) so it shouldn’t be relied on for scripting or automation."

Comment: You are right, @NickVeld. To avoid that scenario, `request` fixture should be used to get the current running test. `request.node` should do.

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to what the accepted answer says, do *not* use `PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST` environment variable. The documentation clearly says "*it shouldn’t be relied on*", and in this case, it is not even what the OP asked for, which is, "*file path of the current file being tested*".

Given the following directory structure:

```
graph/
├── test/
│   └── __init__.py/
│       └── test_graph.py
├── __init__.py
└── functions.py
```

The value of `PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST` from a function `test_bfs` in the file `test_graph.py` is:

```
'graph/test/test_graph.py::test_bfs (call)'
```

Whereas, `request.path` has the value `graph/test/test_graph.py`. This is exactly what the OP asked for.

More about `request: FixtureRequest` [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#request).